# Linq code have errors when i use Distinct()

Tags: linq

Guys I am working on a code and I need to do a distinct selecting just 2 columns. Can you guys tell me what is wrong with this code ?

```
foreach (var lbd in (from lbdrow in Db.LaborDtl
where (lbdrow.Company==epged.Company && epged.EmpID==lbdrow.EmployeeNum && lbdrow.PayrollDate==epged.PayrollDate)
select new {Company==lbdrow.Company && ProjectID==lbdrow.ProjectID})).Distinct()
```

Comment: Is this the full query? If this is it, where are you declaring `epged` at?

Comment: Does this DotNetFiddle do what you are looking for: https://dotnetfiddle.net/SVhakk ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys my apologies for the stupid question i found the solution

```
foreach (var lbd in (from lbdrow in Db.LaborDtl
where (lbdrow.Company==epged.Company && epged.EmpID==lbdrow.EmployeeNum && lbdrow.PayrollDate==epged.PayrollDate)
select new {Company==lbdrow.Company && ProjectID==lbdrow.ProjectID}).Distinct())
```